Is this recursive forecasting right for timeseries analysis?
Training a model just to make a quick prototype
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb

def create_features(df):
    """
    Create time series features based on time series index.
    """
    df = df.copy()
    df["hour"] = df.index.hour
    df["dayofweek"] = df.index.dayofweek
    df["month"] = df.index.month
    df["lag60"] = df["cpu_usage"].shift(60)
    df["lag10"] = df["cpu_usage"].shift(10)
    df["lag1"] = df["cpu_usage"].shift(1)
    return df

# Assume data is your original dataframe
data.index = data["timestamp"]
data_ = data[["cpu_usage"]]

# Create initial features
data_w_features = create_features(data_)
FEATURES = ['hour', 'dayofweek', 'month', 'lag60', 'lag10', 'lag1']
TARGET = ["cpu_usage"]

X = data_w_features[FEATURES]
y = data_w_features[TARGET]

# Train the model
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree',
                        n_estimators=500,
                        early_stopping_rounds=50,
                        objective='reg:linear',
                        max_depth=3,
                        learning_rate=0.01)

reg.fit(X, y, eval_set=[(X, y)], verbose=100)

Now that I train the model I can create the future data and pass it to the model until I get 60 predictions into the future.
# Prepare the last 240 minutes of data
last_240_min_data = data_.tail(240)
future_index = pd.date_range(start=last_240_min_data.index[-1] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1), freq="T", periods=60)

# Create a dataframe to hold the predictions
future_predictions = []

# Copy the last 240 minutes of data to avoid modifying the original dataframe
df_and_future = last_240_min_data.copy()

# Recursive forecasting for 60 minutes
for i in range(60):
    # Create features for the current dataframe
    df_with_features = create_features(df_and_future)
    
    # Get the features for the next prediction
    next_timestamp = df_and_future.index[-1] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
    
    # Ensure the new timestamp is in the dataframe
    if next_timestamp not in df_with_features.index:
        df_with_features.loc[next_timestamp] = [None] * len(df_with_features.columns)
    
    future_with_features = df_with_features.loc[next_timestamp]
    
    # Make the prediction
    pred = reg.predict(future_with_features[FEATURES].values.reshape(1, -1))[0]

    print(pred)
    
    # Append the new prediction to the dataframe using pd.concat
    new_row = pd.DataFrame({"cpu_usage": [pred]}, index=[next_timestamp])
    df_and_future = pd.concat([df_and_future, new_row])
    
    # Append the prediction to the list
    future_predictions.append(pred)
    
    # Keep only the last 240 rows to avoid growing the DataFrame indefinitely
    df_and_future = df_and_future.tail(240)

# Convert predictions to a dataframe
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(future_predictions, index=future_index, columns=["predicted_cpu_usage"])

print(predictions_df)

This are my 60 minute predictions, I dont know why its predicting the same value, is something wrong with this aproach?



Date
Value




2025-11-25 10:58:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 10:59:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:00:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:01:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:02:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:03:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:04:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:05:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:06:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:07:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:08:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:09:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:10:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:11:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:12:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:13:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:14:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:15:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:16:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:17:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:18:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:19:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:20:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:21:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:22:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:23:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:24:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:25:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:26:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:27:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:28:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:29:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:30:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:31:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:32:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:33:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:34:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:35:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:36:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:37:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:38:00
33.314259


2025-11-25 11:39:00
33.314259



